# Major issue with overloading my stream operators in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I really need help in my Advanced Object Oriented Programming class! Here is how the program works; We are coding in C++ and we are to create a program that creates a weather station. if you press '1' you input the temperature, wind speed and direction; if you press '2' if will give you the current weather reading; if you press '3' it will give you the weather history; and if you press '4' you exit. Also, it reads the outputs from a text file and outputs them to the console...I have that all working correctly. The problem i am having trouble with is we are to overload the stream (<< and >>) operators so we no longer have to call the print() function. Previously, i called the print function to print the current weather reading as well as the temperature history. I have excluded my files wind.h and wind.cpp because i havent even started trying to implement the overloading in there yet; plus i think i posted enough code in one post. Also, i should mention that the program also reads output from an english.txt if the user wants english or piglation from piglatin.txt if they want piglatin.

My question, basically, is how do i implement the overloading of operator streams correctly?

Source.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "temp.h"
#include "Wind.h"
#include "Language.h"
#include <fstream>
#define SIZE 10
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Temperature temp1;
    win wind1;
    //Temperature p;
    string windDir[SIZE];
    int windSpeed[SIZE];
    int temp[SIZE];
    //Tem p1(int temp);
    int index=0;
    int reply;
    int reply2;
    int lang;
    int count=0;
    string STRING1, STRING2, STRING3, STRING4, STRING5, STRING6;
    fstream myEngFile;
    fstream myPigFile;
    ofstream out;

    //Language Menu
    cout<<"**** Welcome to The Michael Weather Station! \n";
    cout<<"**** Elcomeway otay Ethay Ichaelmay Eatherway Ationstay! \n";
    cout<<"Please enter 1 for english ";
    cout<<"orway 2 orfay iglatinpay \n";
    cin>>lang;
    cin.clear();

    switch(lang){

        //English Main Menu
    case 1:
    //for(int count=0; count<21; count++)
    for(int index=0; index<SIZE; index++){
    bool menu = true;
    while (menu != false){
    myEngFile.open ("English.txt");
    getline(myEngFile, STRING1);
    cout<<STRING1<<"\n";
    getline(myEngFile, STRING2);
    cout<<STRING2<<"\n";
    getline(myEngFile, STRING3);
    cout<<STRING3<<"\n";
    getline(myEngFile, STRING4);
    cout<<STRING4<<"\n";
    getline(myEngFile, STRING5);
    cout<<STRING5<<"\n";
    cin>>reply;
    cin.clear();
    myEngFile.close();

    switch(reply){

        //Gets data in English
    case 1:
    temp[count]=temp1.getTemp();
    windSpeed[count] =wind1.getSpeed();
    windDir[count] = wind1.getDirection();
    cout<<" \n";
    count++;
    break;

    //Prints data in English
    case 2:
        cout<<"--------------------------------\n";
    //temp1.printTemp(temp[count-1]);
        Temperature p = temp1.getTemp();
    //cout<<temp[count-1];
        cout<<p;
    wind1.printWindMeasurement(windSpeed[count-1], windDir[count-1]);
    cout<<" \n";
    cout<<" \n";
    break;

    //Prints History in English 
    case 3:
        cout<<"---------------------------------- \n";
    //for(int index=SIZE%count; index<SIZE; index++){
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++){
    //temp1.printTemp(temp[i]);
    cout<<temp[i];
    wind1.printWindMeasurement(windSpeed[i], windDir[i]);
    cout<<"\n";
    }
        break;

        //Exits...In English?
    case 4:
        cout<<"Exiting............. \n";
        menu= false;
        break;

        //Cheacks to see that only 1,2,3, or 4 is entered
    default:
        cout<<"Please enter 1,2,3, or 4 only!!! \n";
        cout<<" \n";

    } //Switch(reply) in english

    } //While loop in english

    return 0;

} //For loop in english

    break;

    //PigLatin Main Menu
    case 2:
    for(int index=0; index<SIZE; index++){
    bool menu = true;
    while (menu != false){
    myPigFile.open ("PigLatin.txt");
    getline(myPigFile, STRING1);
    cout<<STRING1<<"\n";
    getline(myPigFile, STRING2);
    cout<<STRING2<<"\n";
    getline(myPigFile, STRING3);
    cout<<STRING3<<"\n";
    getline(myPigFile, STRING4);
    cout<<STRING4<<"\n";
    getline(myPigFile, STRING5);
    cout<<STRING5<<"\n";
    getline(myPigFile, STRING6);
    cout<<STRING6<<"\n";
    cin>>reply2;
    cin.clear();
    myPigFile.close();


    switch(reply2){

        //Gets data in PigLatin
    case 1:
    temp[count]=temp1.getTemp2();
    windSpeed[count] =wind1.getSpeed2();
    windDir[count] = wind1.getDirection2();
    cout<<" \n";
    count++;
    break;

    //Prints data in PigLatin
    case 2:
        cout<<"----------------------------------\n";
    //temp1.printTemp2(temp[count-1]);
    cout<<temp[count-1];
    wind1.printWindMeasurement2(windSpeed[count-1], windDir[count-1]);
    cout<<" \n";
    cout<<" \n";
    break;

    //Prints History in PigLatin
    case 3:
        cout<<"------------------------------------ \n";
    //for(int index=SIZE%count; index<SIZE; index++){
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++){
    //temp1.printTemp2(temp[i]);
    cout<<temp[i];
    wind1.printWindMeasurement2(windSpeed[i], windDir[i]);
    cout<<"\n";
    }
        break;

        //Exits...in PigLatin?
    case 4:
        cout<<"exitingway............. \n";
        menu= false;
        break;

        //Checks to see only 1,2,3, or 4 is entered
    default:
        cout<<"Easeplay enterway 1,2,3, orway 4 onlyway!!! \n";
        cout<<" \n";

    } //Switch (Reply2) in piglatin

    } //While loop for PigLatin Main Menu

    return 0;

} //For loop for PigLatin Main Menu

break;

} //switch(Lang)

} //Main
```

---

Temp.cpp:

```
#include "temp.h"
#include "Language.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

//        Lang La;
        fstream myEngFile5;
        string tempLine5;
        string tempLine6;
        //string tempLine1; // from language file


        /**** Keep the getTemp() method, but get rid of the print method 
        and overload the operators there*******/

ostream &operator<<( ostream &out, const Temperature &p) //&f
{
    //int far=0;
    fstream myEngFile1;
    string tempLine1;
    myEngFile1.open ("English.txt");
    myEngFile1.seekg(194);
    getline(myEngFile1, tempLine1);
    //La.getTempLang();
    out<<p.tempLine1<<endl; // What is the Temperature?
//  cin>>p; //f
    return out;
    //myEngFile1.close();
    }



/*int Temperature::getTemp()
{
    int value=0;
    fstream myEngFile1;
    string tempLine1;
    myEngFile1.open ("English.txt");
    myEngFile1.seekg(194);
    getline(myEngFile1, tempLine1);
    cout<<tempLine1<<"\n"; // What is the Temperature?
    cin>>value;
    return value;
    myEngFile1.close();
    }*/

int Temperature::getTemp2()
{
    int value=0;
    fstream myPigFile1;
    string tempLine1;
    myPigFile1.open ("PigLatin.txt");
    myPigFile1.seekg(254);
    getline(myPigFile1, tempLine1);
    cout<<tempLine1<<"\n"; //What is the Temperature? in piglatin
    cin>>value;
    return value;
    myPigFile1.close();
    }

/*void Tem::printTemp(int temper)
    {
        fstream myEngFile5;
        string tempLine5;
        string tempLine6;
        myEngFile5.open("English.txt");
        myEngFile5.seekg(335);
        getline(myEngFile5, tempLine5);
        cout<<tempLine5<<temper; //The Temperature is
        myEngFile5.seekg(356);
        getline(myEngFile5, tempLine6);
        cout<<tempLine6<<"\n"; //F
    }*/

ostream &operator<<( ostream &out, const Temperature p)
{    
        out<<tempLine5<<p.value; //The Temperature is __
        out<<tempLine6<<"\n"; //F
        return out;
}

istream &operator>>( istream &in, Temperature &p)
{
        //in>>p.value;
        myEngFile5.open("English.txt");
        myEngFile5.seekg(335);
        getline(myEngFile5, tempLine5);
        in>>tempLine5;
        myEngFile5.seekg(356);
        getline(myEngFile5, tempLine6);
        in>>tempLine6;
        return in;
}

/*void Tem::printTemp2(int temper)
    {
        fstream myPigFile4;
        string tempLine5;
        string tempLine6;
        myPigFile4.open("PigLatin.txt");
        myPigFile4.seekg(445);
        getline(myPigFile4, tempLine5);
        cout<<tempLine5<<temper; //The temperature is __ (in piglatin) 
        myPigFile4.seekg(473);
        getline(myPigFile4, tempLine6);
        cout<<tempLine6<<"\n"; //fay
    }*/
```

---

Temp.h:

```
#ifndef TEMP
#define TEMP
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//int index=0;

class Temperature 
{
    int value;
    //char unit;

public:

    string tempLine1;

int getTemp();
int getTemp2();

Temperature()
{
value=0;
//unit='F';
}

Temperature(int v/*, char u*/)
{
    value=v;
    //unit=u;
}
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const Temperature &p); // needs 'friend' i think
friend istream &operator>>(istream &in, Temperature &p);
//friend ostream operator<<(ostream out, const Temperature p);
//friend istream operator>>(istream in, Temperature &p);

//void printTemp(int temper);
//void printTemp2(int temper);
};

#endif
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Are you getting an error? If so, what error?

Comment: I stopped reading when I observed that the post spent a lot of time dealing with things that are completely unrelevant to what you need help with. Weather? Press 1 or 2 for this and that? Do I really need to know that? Reduce your question and code to the bare minimum needed to express your problem and you have a much better chance at someone being willing to help.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I am getting multiple errors, too many to post.

Comment: @mah The first part is background on what the program does. i figured without that, how would you know what the program does?

Comment: @MichaelBranco based on the problem you seem to be having, issues with overloading stream operations, I don't need to know anything at all about your program… I only need to see a _very_ simplified example that attempts to overload stream I/O on a simplified class with nothing to take my focus away from your problem. (A side benefit -- often when going through the exercise of simplifying things like this, you'll find the problem on your own). To use a bad car analogy… if I had problems with my brakes, would you care that I plan to drive to dad's house, through 3 traffic lights and 8 turns?

Comment: @mah That's a good point. I just wasn't sure what was useful and what wasn't... To be honest honest I wasnt even sure where to put everything, so I figured i would just add everything lol

Comment: @MichaelBranco Why not start with the first one? At least then you'd be working on some specific issue.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz well im pretty sure im getting a lot of error based off of other errors, plus admittedly i do not have a dev envir in front of me at the moment

Comment: @MichaelBranco So, what, you got a bunch of errors and didn't look at them? What did you think the errors were for? Okay, I'll give you the answer, they're to tell you what's wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1):

So. Here's the first point. mah is completely correct with his comment. There is a **ton** of irrelevant code in your problem.

So, to start, let's remove it. And reduce the scope of your problem to the size that someone might care to read.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Temperature
{
    private:
        int value;

    public:
        Temperature(): value(0) {
        }

        explicit Temperature(int v): value(v) {
        }

        friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const Temperature &p);
        friend istream &operator>>(istream &in, Temperature &p);
};

ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const Temperature &p)
{
    fstream myEngFile1;
    string tempLine1;
    myEngFile1.open ("English.txt");
    myEngFile1.seekg(194);
    getline(myEngFile1, tempLine1);
    out << p.tempLine1 << endl; // What is the Temperature?
    out << tempLine5 << p.value; //The Temperature is __
    out << tempLine6 << "\n"; //F
    return out;
}

istream &operator>>( istream &in, Temperature &p)
{
    //in>>p.value;
    myEngFile5.open("English.txt");
    myEngFile5.seekg(335);
    getline(myEngFile5, tempLine5);
    in>>tempLine5;
    myEngFile5.seekg(356);
    getline(myEngFile5, tempLine6);
    in>>tempLine6;
    return in;
}

int main() {
    Temperature x;
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

This is more or less your code, but with things like your comments removed (why do I care that your temperature class will use a F/C comparison in the future). Also, let's get rid of all of your menu structure. I don't care about that either, and you claim that it works fine.

So, now we have a reasonable amount of code to look at, so let's just show a reasonable implementation of an ostream and istream overload.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

class Temperature
{
    private:
        int value;

    public:
        Temperature(): value(0) {
        }

        explicit Temperature(int v): value(v) {
        }

        friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Temperature &p);
        friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, Temperature &p);
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Temperature & p)
{
    out << "Temperature(" << p.value << ")";
    return out;
}

std::istream &operator>>( std::istream &in, Temperature &p)
{
    in >> p.value;
    return in;
}

int main() {
    Temperature x;
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

If we execute this....

```
[2:48pm][wlynch@watermelon /tmp] ./foo
123
Temperature(123)
[2:48pm][wlynch@watermelon /tmp] ./foo
-9000
Temperature(-9000)
```

Comment: I don't see how your answer helps, only because all you really did was get rid of my code that reads in output from a file, im gonna need that down the road anyway. Otherwise it all looks pretty similar, besides the fact you got rid of 'using namespace std' and put std:: where appropriate...Can you explain if i am incorrect? @sharth

Comment: From what I understand of your problem statement. You have a working method called `printTemp()` (which is either commented out, or not included). You would like to use a `std::ostream` overload instead of `printTemp()`. The code I've provided is the basics of doing that. If you need the output in a particular format, then it's not a giant leap from what I've done here. If you need to output to a file, then that is outside the scope of an ostream overload. That code does not belong in that function, and instead, probably should exist in your main.

Comment: Also, I understand that reading from a file (for example) is necessary to you down the road. However, is it necessary to the people helping you with the smaller problem, of how do you implement ostream overloads?

Comment: And finally, if you don't find this helpful, I'd be happy to just delete it.

Comment: Well basically what I am asking is that putting the code to read from a file inside the scope of an ostream overload was what was causing my errors? @sharth